# Issue when committing/communicating to SVN from NetBeans with 1.7 client

Tags: svn, netbeans, windows-7, tortoisesvn

Currently when I call update/commit from TortoiseSVN from context menu in Windows Explorer, everything succeeds.

But if I do that from inside Netbeans using the integrated SVN, I get an error as below screen shot.

Why am I getting that error on my machine?

PS: I'm trying to use SVN 1.7 client version via this useful post http://diigo.com/0kf71

[image]

### Edit

I tried the nightly built version with SlikSVN client for version 1.7 but still failed as below screenshot

[image]

### Update

Up to today, Netbeans 7.1 RC1 has been released. The IDE works great with svn repositories whose urls start with `http://` but failed with the ones start with `svn://` e.g. svn://url.of.domain.

Do you have any idea to by-pass it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. If you don't have any important changes then just drop your copy and make a fresh checkout (with fresh authentication) with Netbeans.
2. If you do have relevant changes then it might be easiest to checkout another copy, then diff the two directories with [Kdiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) and copy over what you need. Then checkin the changed files in new copy.
3. **Wait for an NB update** (as Lazy Badger pointed out below, this is the solution). Just stick to TortoiseSVN for now.

Comment: I've tried your #1 suggestion but the question is: how to `make a fresh checkout` using Netbeans?

Comment: Go to Team > Subversion > Checkout

Comment: I tried checking out using Netbeans but trying to enter my svn account results in the above error though :( - this happens a one specific svn repository. I tried another repository from another svn server, it works. Any ideas Andruso? Thank you

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the Netbeans SVN checkout window? If not, then what is the repo protocol(https, svn+ssh, etc)?

Comment: The repo protocol is `svn://<the ip>/<the repo and path>. Sorry I don't have the screenshot for you

Comment: You have to wait next version of Netbeans, which *will support* SVN 1.7

Comment: Up to today, Netbeans 7.1 RC1 has been released. The IDE works great with svn repositories whose urls start with http:// but failed with the ones start with svn:// e.g. svn://url.of.domain.

Do you have nay idea to by-pass it?

Answer (score 0):

For me Netbeans 7.0.1  and subversion 1.7 is working on windows 7.

Just Use -J-DsvnClientAdapterFactory=commandline switch and install SlikSvn 32bit.

Don't forget to add the svn path in tools->options->miscellaneous->vesioning->subversion and update link target 
Eg:  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.0\bin\netbeans.exe" -J-DsvnClientAdapterFactory=commandline`

It dose not work with the TortoiseSVN command line client.

Comment: @Baciu Thank you. But I get authentication error when using this. SlikSvn's commandline when called alone raise the error too. My repo url starts with svn://url.of.domain

Comment: Up to today, Netbeans 7.1 RC1 has been released. The IDE works great with svn repositories whose urls start with http:// but failed with the ones start with svn:// e.g. svn://url.of.domain.

Do you have nay idea to by-pass it?

Comment: With Netbeans 7.1 RCx, this setting is automatically turned on already

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Netbeans 7.1